# How do I remove this button in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I remove this button in IntelliJ?

[image]

It is the overriden notification button, I also want to get rid of the implemented one, which should be the same setting.

Comment: @Meo I think it is redundant as I see if a method is overridden with the annotation and if I want to go to a super/subclass I just use the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Well, then you need to make a feature request.